# SQL Query to find difference between two times

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DATE                  |  ID |    PARAM_TYPE
07-08-2012 10:10:53 AM| 5613|   INPUT
07-08-2012 10:10:59 AM| 5613|   OUTPUT
07-08-2012 10:16:34 AM| 5624|   INPUT
07-08-2012 10:16:42 AM| 5624|   OUTPUT
07-08-2012 08:09:08 AM| 5503|   INPUT
07-08-2012 08:09:15 AM| 5503|   OUTPUT
```

Table name : `EMP_RECORDS`
I want to display the time difference between `INPUT` and `OUTPUT`,as Single record.

For example :

```
   DATE               |ID   |  PARAM_TYPE
07-08-2012 10:10:53 AM| 5613|   INPUT
07-08-2012 10:10:59 AM| 5613|   OUTPUT
```

AS

```
ID  |Difference
5613| 6 min
```

Comment: Does every `id` has **one** INPUT and **one** OUTPUT?

Comment: Normally, Oracle SQL Developer is used with Oracle and not MySQL.  I am changing the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LAG` analytic function:

```
SELECT id,
       ( output_date - input_date ) * 24 * 60 AS minutes_difference
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         "DATE" as output_date,
         LAG( CASE param_type WHEN 'INPUT' THEN "DATE" END )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE" ) AS input_date,
         param_type
  FROM   EMP_RECORDS
)
WHERE  param_type = 'OUTPUT';
```

Comment: I prefer the LAG approach over other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join for that where one table has the input and one has the output:

```
SELECT a.ID AS ID,(b.DATE-a.DATE) AS Difference
FROM EMP_RECORDS AS a
     JOIN EMP_RECORDS AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.PARAM_TYPE = 'INPUT' AND b.PARAM_TYPE = 'OUTPUT'
```

Answer (score -1):

I would join them together like this (is written, not tested):

```
SELECT t1.ID as ID, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.DATE, t2.DATE) as difference FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t2.ID=t1.ID AND t2.PARAM_TYPE = 'OUTPUT') WHERE t1.PARAM_TYPE = 'INPUT';
```

Read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: The question has been re-tagged from MySQL to Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

PLS CHANGE THE COLUMN NAME DATE:ONLY FOR SQL

```
SELECT
      A.id,
      DATEDIFF(A.date_val,B.date_val) AS duration
      FROM EMP_RECORDS A
      JOIN EMP_RECORDS B
      ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.PARAM_TYPE = "INPUT"
      B.PARAM_TYPE = "OUTPUT";
```

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATEDIFF` function.